# Fiddler 4 Certificate error on Windows

Tags: windows, https, fiddler

I am using Fiddler to monitor HTTPS traffic for our private project. After upgrading to Windows 10 and installing Fiddler, I am unable to create a root certificate. I tried using Both CertEnroll and MakeCert and both returned that they cannot create a root certificate:

> 09:53:54:2275 Fiddler.CertMaker> [C:\Program Files (x86)\Fiddler2\MakeCert.exe -r -ss my -n "CN=DO_NOT_TRUST_FiddlerRoot, O=DO_NOT_TRUST, OU=Created by http://www.fiddler2.com" -sky signature -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -h 1 -cy authority -a sha256 -m 132 -b 01/07/2015 ] Returned Error: Creation of the interception certificate failed.
>
> makecert.exe returned -1.
>
> Results from C:\Program Files (x86)\Fiddler2\MakeCert.exe -r -ss my -n "CN=DO_NOT_TRUST_FiddlerRoot, O=DO_NOT_TRUST, OU=Created by http://www.fiddler2.com" -sky signature -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -h 1 -cy authority -a sha256 -m 132 -b 01/07/2015
>
> Error: Can't create the key of the subject ('JoeSoft')
>   Failed

AND

> 09:43:37:0332 /Fiddler.CertMaker> Invoking CertEnroll for Subject: CN=DO_NOT_TRUST_FiddlerRoot, O=DO_NOT_TRUST, OU=Created by http://www.fiddler2.com; Thread's ApartmentState: MTA
>   09:43:39:0853 !ERROR: Failed to generate Certificate using CertEnroll. System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. < CertEnroll::CX509PrivateKey::Create: The requested operation cannot be completed. The computer must be trusted for delegation and the current user account must be configured to allow delegation. 0x80090345 (-2146892987 SEC_E_DELEGATION_REQUIRED)

Every time when changing the service I Reset All Certificates and/or Removed Interception Certificates. Also the key in `AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Crypt/RSA/{LONG_ID}` is nowhere to be found (the folder is always empty).
After browsing through forums, I followed some instructions and downloaded the Bouncy Castle Certificate Maker (the one suggested for Android) and that one created 2 root certificates and added them to Windows so they will be trusted. After doing so, all my HTTPS traffic looked like HTTP with tunneling. When looking into that issue, I found that in Text view it said

> "This is a CONNECT tunnel, through which encrypted HTTPS traffic flows.
>   Fiddler's HTTPS Decryption feature is enabled, but this specific tunnel was configured not to be decrypted. Settings can be found inside Tools > Fiddler Options > HTTPS."

AND the logger returned a few of the following:

> "10:02:38:5419 !Certificate cache didn't find certificate for [server.com]. Returning null to thread #30. ___ 10:02:38:5419 fiddler.https> Failed to obtain certificate for server.com due to Certificate Maker returned null when asked for a certificate for server.com"
>
> "Failed to create certificate for server.com: The requested operation cannot be completed. The computer must be trusted for delegation and the current user account must be configured to allow delegation."

In the properties of a tunneling connection, I found

> "X-HTTPS-DECRYPTION-ERROR: Could not find or generate interception certificate."

Do you have any solutions for me? I'd really appreciate it. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, it seems that in the end it was a Windows Issue.
My PC is part of the company Domain and even though my user was an Administrator of this PC, not everything was fully functional (for example I could run as Administrator any app with no problem, but couldn't create a Root Certificate).
The issue was found by my colleague in the **Windows Credentials Manager** and he fixed it with the following Registration Entry (*.reg*):

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\Protect\Providers\df9d8cd0-1501-11d1-8c7a-00c04fc297eb]
"ProtectionPolicy"=dword:00000001
```

I hope this helps someone avoid hours of searching on the internet for a fix.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Reset All Cerificates]

You need to reset Fiddler Root Certificate , 
After that everything will be fine

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but no. I did that every few minutes when trying stuff. The sollution was as I stated above, a windows problem.

Comment: Didn't worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

It *is* a Windows issue: my company has just released an update to its version of Windows10 and I started seeing the certificate errors described above. Editing the registry was the only think that made Fiddler and website navigation work again